# Is it possible to cancel the browser's getUserMedia webcam permissions dialog in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dialog, webcam, getusermedia

I have two buttons: **webcamOn** and **webcamOff**

When the user clicks webcamOn, I request getUserMedia webcam access.

When the user clicks webcamOff, I stop the stream using:

```
function stopWebcam() {
    if(stream) {
        stream.stop();
    }
}
```

...which works fine if the user has already accepted the browser's request dialog.

However, if the user never accepts the request and then clicks webcamOff, the dialog is never removed.

Is it possible to cancel the browser dialog in Javascript?

Comment: Why don't you disable the Off button until the user grants access?

Comment: Yep, that's a good workaround, but is it actually possible to cancel the browser's request dialog directly with Javascript?

Comment: No..there is no way you can do this..